# Simulating SMS on Android tablet for application testing

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, tablet

Hi I am in am taking an Android development class and we are supposed to develop an app that responds to incoming sms messages. I was wanting to know if there is a way to broadcast sms messages in one app so my broadcastReceiver in the other app can handle said sms messages. Since I am working on a tablet true sms is not available. Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an emulator and then send sms to it via the Emulator control section of DDMS

Here I have created an ICS based tablet and I can send it an SMS via the emulator control:

[image: Here I have created an ICS based tablet and I can send it an SMS via the emulator control]

Comment: Ok so the only way to do it is inside an emulator. Thanks.

Comment: Yup, you can also try connecting a tablet with a built-in telephony sub-system (like the new Samsung galaxy Tab 2) to your computer and see if you can send sms to the device in a similar way. Glad I could help.

Comment: Scratch that silly question. No cellular = no sms, though messaging over wifi is certainly possible.